# How program can recognize if I am running another?

Tags: python, windows, security

There is a game I play that I want to automate some tasks in.
Not hacking just consistently print screening and execute fake keyboard outputs.
So I wrote some python code and packaged it into a .exe with pyinstaller so I can also share it with others.
The problem is, I know that the game autobans for using known macro softwares like macro recorder, AutoHotKey etc...

The game runs on windows with admin privileges, so I know it can probably gets a list of my running processes..
My question is, **how can I protect myself**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to protect yourself against a program that can see all processes, without turning it into something like a rootkit. However, there is a good chance your program won't be flagged, since you made it yourself and I doubt python itself is flagged. It depends on what game in particular you are referring to.

Comment: What about maybe changing the process name everytime the program is launched? I just wanna protect it in case I gonna sell it for other players in the future.

Comment: @junior_developer181 In Windows no there is not. However in process list it should just show up as "pythonw.exe" I believe. What game is it?